# Removing specific Item in Strings?

Tags: python, string

So the problem im having is im trying to take out each letter in ana2 as i go along checking the anagram. But when i replace the item it takes out ALL of that letter from the anagram so when it hits the 2nd T it stops. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
clue2 = "S#tatue# of Libert#y"
clue3 = "T#om Mar##volo R#iddle#"

CLUE1 = clue1.upper().replace("#",'').replace(" ",'')
CLUE2 = clue2.upper().replace("#",'').replace(" ",'')
CLUE3 = clue3.upper().replace("#",'').replace(" ",'')

print("CLUE1 is",CLUE1)
print("CLUE2 is",CLUE2)
print("CLUE3 is",CLUE3)

ana1 = "HERECOMEDOTS" #stores hypothesis in constant
ana2 = "BUILDTOSTAIFREE"
ana3 = "IIMLORDVOLDEMORT"
print()

print('Testing Hypothesis 1 HERECOMEDOTS')

for item in CLUE1 : #executes a for loop that compares character by character of each word to see if they contain the same. 
    if item in ana1:
        print(item, "in clue is in my hypothesis. Continue.") #if else statements to print the according statements if conditions are met 
    else:
        print(item, "in the clue is NOT in my hypothesis. Thus, my hypothesis is false.\nCLUE1 is NOT an anagram!")

print('CLUE1 is an anagram!')

print() #spaces for desired output

print('Testing Hypothesis 2 BUILDTOSTAIFREE')

for item in CLUE2 :
    if item in ana2:
        ana2 = ana2.replace(item,'')
        print(item, "in clue is in my hypothesis. Continue.")
    else:
        print(item, "in the clue is NOT in my hypothesis. Thus, my hypothesis is false.\nCLUE2 is NOT an anagram!")
        break

print()
print('Testing Hypothesis 3 IIMLORDVOLDEMORT')

for item in CLUE3 :
    if item in ana3:
        print(item, "in clue is in my hypothesis. Continue.")
    else:
        print(item, "in the clue is NOT in my hypothesis. Thus, my hypothesis is false.\nCLUE3 is NOT an anagram!")
        break``
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` function has an optional `count` parameter that allows you to limit the number of times it replaces. Set it to `1` to only replace the first match.

```
        ana2 = ana2.replace(item,'', 1)
```

Comment: Its just leaving the 1 there no count but this saved my life thank you beautiful human.